# Is it necessary add IsAuthenticated permissions to permission_classes in view that is inherited from LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I have a class-based view called `ProfileDetail`. It is inherit `LoginRequiredMixin` from `django.contrib.auth.mixins`. And then set `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`. Basically all client that view `ProfileDetail` is already logged-in, hence authenticated. My question is, is it necessary to set `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` even though all client already logged-in? What's your advice? Thank you.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from .models import Profile
from .serializers import ProfileSerializer


class ProfileDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Comment: In DRF, the authentication is handled differently than the *native* Django. So, depending on the type of view you're using, it will be different.

Comment: I'm new to Django and DRF, so basically i don't know the small things happen behind the scene. This view is just basic. Only show detail of user profile. So, is it better to set `IsAuthenticated` in `permission_classes`?

Comment: In your case, you don't have to use the `LoginRequiredMixin` on `ProfileDetail`

Comment: Thanks @JPG for your response, sorry for late reply. I will take your approach.